# Delete multiple rows from DatagridView (Transfer to Subtable)

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am writing a code where I transfer rows between two datagridiews. The rows I selected are transferred to the sub table and I want the transferred rows to be deleted from the table above. However, with this code I wrote, only the last row is deleted from the table, but all of them are transferred to the table below. here is my codes

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
```

where is my mistake?
can you help me?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you expecting the checked rows to be in the `SelectedRows` collection? I don't recall the GridView having that feature.

Comment: So how can I do what I want? It was always like this in the code samples.

Comment: I think the ASP.NET grid has that feature, maybe that's what you were seeing? Anyway, set the [SelectionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) to your preference, then select the rows with your mouse. The selected rows should all be highlighted, not just one as in your screenshot.

Comment: Or, if you want to use the Select column, just use the data bound to it to consider it "selected". That means you won't use the `SelectedRows` property, you'll be rolling your own logic.